# what is difference between angular and meteor?

Tags: angularjs, meteor

what is difference between angular and meteor?

as I know both follow model view view-model  architecture, then also what is difference between these two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well... I think the simplest answer to your question would be:

> AngularJS is a client UI Framework whereas Meteor is a full stack framework for client & server development which has embedded database support for mongodb (this is the default, other db's are also supported by the community)

A bit more detailed discussion can be found here:

[Major design differences between Angular, React, and Blaze (client-side Meteor)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723780/difference-between-angular-and-client-side-portion-of-meteor-where-they-overlap)